# Executing native query with Hibernate 4.1

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate with C3P0 connection pool. In Hibernate 3 I could get access to wrapped C3P0ProxyConnection through `BorrowedConnectionProxy` and then perform `rawConnectionOperation`. From what I see `BorrowedConnectionProxy` is not a part of Hibernate 4.1 anymore.

Is it any way I can run vendor specific queries ? (An instance of proxy connection inside `Work.execute` does not work for me, I need to execute Oracle stored procedure that takes collection of custom object type).

Thank you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get access to the unproxied Connection in Work by calling:

```
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    Connection unproxiedConnection = connection.unwrap( Connection.class );
    ...
}
```

That form leverages the JDBC 4 unwrap method, we simply delegate that to the underlying connection.  Or if you specifically need an OracleConnection:

```
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
    ...
}
```

You could also use:

```
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    Connection unproxiedConnection = ( (JdbcWrapper<Connection>) connection ).getWrappedObject();
    ...
}
```

I have gone back and forth in terms of contemplating allowing the Work to signify that it wants an unproxied Connection, but given the availability of Connection#unwrap I am not so sure there is an real benefit.

Comment: Hi this failed in our code - if you get a chance please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269894/getting-a-handle-to-native-oracle-connection-in-hibernate-4-to-run-a-stored-proc