# Getting a handle to native Oracle Connection in Hibernate 4 to run a stored proc

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jboss

This is a follow-up to [Executing native query with Hibernate 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524984/executing-native-query-with-hibernate-4-1)

I've tried the options in the listed answer but we get errors and are unable to unwrap the proxied connection into the native connection which Oracle needs

Option 2 code

```
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
    ...
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) at $Proxy64.unwrap(Unknown Source)
```

Option 3 code

```
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    Connection unproxiedConnection = ( (JdbcWrapper<Connection>) connection ).getWrappedObject();
    ...
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:158) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:126) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
at com.xxx.massBookingUpdateParam(HoldoversDAO.java:312) [Business-1.jar:]
at com.xxx.saveHoldovers(HoldoversServiceBean.java:86) [Business-1.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:129) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:137) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:74) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:227) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
... 71 more
```

any suggestions?

I've also tried this option [SessionFactory.openSession(Connection) in Hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731266/sessionfactory-opensessionconnection-in-hibernate-4) but that class does not get instantiated at all

**Update:**

Option 2 code works correctly. The problem was we had 2 versions of ojbc.jar - one as a Jboss module and one within the EAR, hence the Exception.

Comment: Why would your "Option 3 code" cause that error?  You never attempt to cast the Connection to an Oracle connection.  In general you need to understand that connection pools and data sources usually "wrap" connections as well.  As for "Option 2 code", Hibernate would simply delegate that call to the underlying connection it has.  But that is causing an error.  So there error there is in that Connection's unwrap method.  I assume that is this JBoss WrappedConnectionJDK6 class.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace for Option 2?

Comment: @Steve Ebersole: we got by with this `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection oc = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection) connection.getMetaData().getConnection();`

Comment: Not sure why you would think that would work.  If something is proxying the driver, it does not just proxy the Connection generally speaking.  And as I asked already, do you have the full exception output for the "Option 2" error?

Comment: @SteveEbersole: "Option 2" works - please see my update. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 code works correctly.

ie.

`OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );`

The problem was we had 2 versions of ojbc.jar - one as a Jboss module and one within the EAR, hence the ClassCastException.

As mentioned in the comments, this code also works

`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection oc = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection) connection.getMetaData().getConnection();`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

I had encountered the same issue. We were using spring and it has a class called
NativeJdbcExtractor. It has many implementations and the following one works for TomCat.  There is a specific implementation for Jboss called the JBossNativeJdbcExtractor

```
<bean id="jdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"></bean>
```

In your DAO you can inject the bean and use the following method

```
protected NativeJdbcExtractor jdbcExtractor;
Connection conn=jdbcExtractor.getNativeConnection(oracleConnection);
```