# SqlStructArrayValue : pass list of objects to Array of structs in Oracle storedprocedure

Tags: arrays, oracle, struct, spring-data, procedure

I am using JDBCTemplate to create the connection pool and get `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`

---

### I was trying to pass a list of objects from Java to a procedure in Oracle using spring data extension package.

---

**Steps followed**
Created an array and struct in Oracle.
**Array Created using**:

```
DROP TYPE SCHEMA_NAME.TB_T_TYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA_NAME.TB_T_TYPE is table of T_TYPE;
/
```

**Struct Created using**:

```
DROP TYPE SCHEMA_NAME.T_TYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA_NAME.T_TYPE is object ( 
NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
ATTRIBUTE1 VARCHAR2(100),
ATTRIBUTE2 VARCHAR2(100) 
)
/
```

**Created a Procedure** in **Schema Level**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SCHEMA_NAME.POPULATE_TABLE_TEST (example TB_T_TYPE) as 
type t_tb_seq is table of number; 
l_t_seq t_tb_seq := t_tb_seq(); 
begin 
for i in 1.. example.count loop 
l_t_seq.extend; 
select 1 into l_t_seq(i) from dual; 
end loop; 
forall i in 1.. example.count 
insert into TABLE_TEST(id,name,attribute1,attribute2) 
values (l_t_seq(i), 
treat(example(i) as T_TYPE).NAME,
treat(example(i) as T_TYPE).ATTRIBUTE1, 
treat(example(i) as T_TYPE).ATTRIBUTE2 
); 
end;
/
```

**Java**
 1. **Spring Context file**: I added accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed = true

 2. **Created function in DAO impl**:

```
private final String ORACLE_STRUCT = "SEATMGR.T_TYPE "; 
private final String ORACLE_ARRAY = "SEATMGR.TB_T_TYPE"; 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testingArray(List<SeatAssignmentDetails> assignmentDetails) throws Exception {
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;
    try {
        List<TestObject> objects = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
        TestObject[]  testArray = new TestObject[assignmentDetails.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (SeatAssignmentDetails seatAssignmentDetails : assignmentDetails) {
            TestObject obj = new TestObject();
            obj.setCity(seatAssignmentDetails.getCity());
            obj.setSite(seatAssignmentDetails.getSite());
            obj.setState(seatAssignmentDetails.getState());
            testArray[i] = obj;
            i++;
        }
        simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(
                sspaDBConnection.getJDBCTemplate());
        StructMapper<TestObject> mapper = new BeanPropertyStructMapper<TestObject>();
        simpleJdbcCall
                //              .withCatalogName("pkg_SSEQ_queries")
                .withProcedureName("POPULATE_TABLE_TEST")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("example",Types.ARRAY,ORACLE_ARRAY));
        simpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(
                "example", new SqlStructArrayValue<TestObject>(
                        testArray, mapper,
                        ORACLE_STRUCT, ORACLE_ARRAY)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Horrible errrrrrr",e);
    }
}
```

I have been reading that if you use regular procedure call without using SimpleJdbcCall you will be able to cast the Poolable connection created by JDBCTemplate to regular Oracle connection by using **((DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegate();** in the connection passed to the array descriptor object.

**Issue**: 
The above java function fails on the execute line by throwing this exception: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`

Thanks in advance.
Sam.

Comment: Classic issue many get. Nothing issue with code, but you have 2 different versions of oracle driver in your classpath! probably your project setup itself and one with ur container

Comment: Thank You for replying.
I am pretty sure we have only one oracle version. ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar is what we defined in our pom.xml file.

Comment: This [Answer should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269894/getting-a-handle-to-native-oracle-connection-in-hibernate-4-to-run-a-stored-proc)

Comment: Thank You again for the prompt reply.

I did look at the link provided. 

I would have achieved what the link provided by using ((DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegate() that is mentioned in the post above.

Unfortunately, I was not able to get access to the connection object since we are using Spring JDBCTemplate. I am using the Spring Data Extension apis, it does not give access to casting the connection object.
Thanks again,
Sam

Comment: Sorry .. I missed ur updated comment. I wish I had hands on your environment.. Not a pro to guess it any further!

Comment: Thanks for helping out though. This is more of a Spring Data Extension package issue.

Comment: try overriding the createTypeValue method of SqlStructArrayValue, you then have access to the connection and are able to unwrap the connection to expose the OracleConnection. The OracleConnection can then be used avoiding the class cast exception. If you need an example then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a third-party connection pool to work with Oracle RDBMS.
`SqlStructArrayValue` should work with `OracleConnection`.
Therefore, you need to make unwrap the physical connection from your connection pool.

```java
OracleConnection oconn = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

In this case, you need to extend `SqlStructArrayValue` and unwrap `OracleConnection` from your connection pool.

```java
public class OracleSqlStructArrayValue<T> extends SqlStructArrayValue {

    public OracleSqlStructArrayValue(T[] values, StructMapper<T> mapper, String structTypeName) {
        super(values, mapper, structTypeName);
    }

    public OracleSqlStructArrayValue(T[] values, StructMapper<T> mapper, String structTypeName, String arrayTypeName) {
        super(values, mapper, structTypeName, arrayTypeName);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        if (!conn.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)) {
            throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException("Oracle types supports only OracleConnection");
        }

        OracleConnection oconn = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

        return super.createTypeValue(oconn, sqlType, typeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use tag in your answer and some description what the answer does